# How to change default value in the calender

Tags: php, html

[image: this is what i get when i try to set date]I am using [this](https://phppot.com/php/php-calendar-event-management-using-fullcalendar-javascript-library/) calender.Here i am trying to change the value based on user input

in html i have

```
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="text" name ="calendar" id="calendar"> </div>
        </div>
```

i can able get this input as value to php page.
i want to give the value as default date in the calender which i gives in the link

i tried this

```
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
   defaultDate: "<?php echo $_GET['calendar']; ?>"
     });
```

this shows a new calender .
but i want to set the date to the existing calender.Any help???

Comment: _“Here i am trying to change the value”_ - what value are you talking about? The code you have shown calls `datepicker`, but the function to call to initialize, or specify different option for the calendar, that would be `fullCalendar`.

Comment: @CBroe Thank You Soo much..That is my Mistake..i changed datepicker to fullCalender.That Works.

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong `id`.

In js you are referring to `id='#calender'`, but in html you have datepicker

Try changing this:

```
$('#calendar').datepicker({
   defaultDate: "<?php echo $_GET['datepicker']; ?>"
     });
```

to

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   defaultDate: "<?php echo $_GET['datepicker']; ?>"
     });
```

> Assuming that you have imported jquery and other related datepicker (css & js) files

Comment: Sorry.thats my mistake i corrected it .but still problem

Answer (score 0):

Using reference to official docs, you should look for the correct version of this package.

- Use `initialDate` for `v5`. Reference: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialDate
- Use `defaultDate` for `v4`. Reference: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/defaultDate

Note: As per official docs, **When not specified, this value defaults to the current date.**

Now as Ankit Jindal already mentioned on of the issue that you were using wrong id in your code. That being said use following code snippet based on your version.

V5 Code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   initialDate: "<?php echo $_GET['datepicker']; ?>"
});
```

V4 Code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   defaultDate: "<?php echo $_GET['datepicker']; ?>"
});
```

Note: Make sure you're getting input data in PHP as $_GET. If not sure use $_REQUEST.

If you're not able to set that while creating an object, try another way. Set it after creating instance of calendar object.

```
strDate = "<?php echo $_GET['datepicker']; ?>";
$('#datepicker').fullCalendar('gotoDate', strDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay sir.i corrected my id's.and i tried this.still problem exist and i tried with $_REQUEST NOW